# jQuery change() event - Not with bind(), live(), keyup+keydown+keypress, nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've looked at various posts on SO about this topic. I am making a character down-counter (ex. '98 Characters Left') for a textbox, the only event I can get it to fire for is `keydown()`, but it doesn't handle it when text is pastes into the textbox. I have tried making an `updateCharCount()` function and setting it to every event (all at one time, and each individually: keyup, keydown, keypress, change.

I have also tried setting the handler with `bind()` and `live()`. If I try to set the handler for keydown & keyup at the same time, neither of the fire, change just plain doesn't fire at all no matter what although everywhere I read that is the solution. How could this be?

Also, I am getting some strange behavior when I only handle the `keydown()` event. (BTW I have the maxLength attribute on my textbox set to 100) If I type to the max character count, backspace once or twice, then type to the max count again, it will read '1 Character(s) Left' even though it is maxed out, and if I backspace once from there it reads '0 Characters(s) Left'. Here's my code:

```
function updateCharCount(){
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    var count = $("#usermsg").attr("maxLength") - clientmsg.length;
    $("#charsleft").html(count);
}
$("#usermsg").keydown(updateCharCount());
```

If anyone could explain the strange behavior that would be nice, but what I REALLY want to know is why if .change() is so widely used, it doesn't work for me, nor .bind('change', ...) or .live('change', ...)

Comment: I haven't read the full post, but the first thing that struck me is the handler function -> `$("#usermsg").keydown(updateCharCount);` <-- Note: removed  `()`

Comment: @Vega - What you pointed out may well be the fix.

Comment: @Vega I give you partial credit for the answer, but your post was a comment so, ;)

Comment: @BrandonMiller Was too lazy at that moment to read the whole post ;) but thanks and good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind multiple events using **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** (bind and live have been deprecated) like this:

```
$("#usermsg").on({
    change: updateCharCount,
    keyup: updateCharCount,
    keydown: updateCharCount
})​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YWSrP/)**

Comment: keydown will not help with counter update as at that moment text in field is not changed yet.

Comment: @FAngel - that's fine. I wanted to show the OP how to bind multiple events and properly call the function and leave it up to them to determine which ones to use.

Comment: When I used that code not only does it not work, but the rest of the code that comes after it doesnt work. And I copied it exactly as you wrote it (adding the ';' of course) tried without the semi-colon afterwards for good measure

Comment: @BrandonMiller - Did you try the example on jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on the example, but when I try it it doesn't work, I am on Google Chrome btw.

Comment: @BrandonMiller - I'm on Chrome too. If it works in the fiddle but not in your site then you may have other code that is causing a conflict.

Comment: @BrandonMiller - pasted your pastebin code into a fiddle and it still seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xnX8k/

Comment: Would you look at that, it does. That is very, very strange... Ugh, this is giving me a headache, and it would do no use to show the whole webpage because that is the only script there.

Comment: Well, after fiddling with it, I finally got it to work by setting them all individually instead of the way you provided:
`$("#usermsg").change(updateCharCount);`
`$("#usermsg").keypress(updateCharCount);`
`$("#usermsg").keyup(updateCharCount);`
Must've been the '()' at the end but the way you provided should have worked

Comment: @BrandonMiller - what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.3, have a feeling that is the problem with the proper way to handle multiple events

Comment: @BrandonMiller - that explains it. `.on()` didn't come around until 1.7.

Comment: Well, Vega pointed out the `()` but it is this answer that eventually led me to the conclusion and the original would have worked if I was using the right version, accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyup` instead of `keydown` as keydown happens BEFORE symbol is inserted.

Change with text field will happen only when focus leave that field. If something changed, but not any time you add a symbol

Keyup will also handle paste event.

Comment: Good to know keyup handles the paste event, but I would like to use them both for when the user holds down a key, when I only use keydown it works for each character occurence while the key is held down, but neither of them work when I try to use them in conjunction

Comment: @BrandonMiller keypress event will repeat for each symbol if user holds a key

Comment: @BrandonMiller [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html) is an order of events and explanation of when each of them is fired

Comment: Also good to know, but when I try to use them in conjuntion neither of them work.